# How do I make a linear graphing calculator in Python with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Why doesn't this code work when I try to graph? The y-intercept doesn't seem to work.

```
from turtle import *

m = float(input("What is the slope? "))

b = float(input("What is the y-intercept? "))

x= window_width()

y= window_height()

y= int(m*x + b)

pd()

goto(x , y)

pd()

goto(-x,-y)

pu()

goto(x/2,0)

pd()

goto(-x/2,0)


pu()

goto(0,2*y)

pd()

goto(0,-2*y)

update()
```

When I test values with y-intercepts, they go throgh the origin, which means it's not working. I'm trying to get the y-intercept working.

Comment: I don't see you even call `t = Turtle()` to begin with.

Comment: @Xion, turtle doesn't require a cal to `Turtle()` as the *default* turtle can be used if only one turtle is needed.  This is the *functional* interface to turtle as opposed to the *object-oriented* one.  And should be avoided for anything but very simple programs.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this code work when I try to graph?

I see two issues: 1) you seem to be doing things in the wrong order; 2) you incorrectly assume that if y is f(x) then f(-x) is -y which isn't true:

```
from turtle import *

m = float(input("What is the slope? "))

b = float(input("What is the y-intercept? "))

x, y = window_width(), window_height()

# Draw Axes
penup()
goto(x / 2, 0)
pendown()
goto(-x / 2, 0)
penup()
goto(0, y / 2)
pendown()
goto(0, -y / 2)

# Plot function

y = int(m * x + b)

penup()
goto(x, y)

x = -x
y = int(m * x + b)

pendown()
goto(x, y)

done()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
What is the slope? 0.5
What is the y-intercept? 100
>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]